# Append() outputs string incorrectly "&lt;" BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 to append a list of img tags to a div object (with id="plotsdiv"). It appends the strings just fine, and when I print them in the for loop, the output looks good:

but it is appended strangely with `&lt;` instead of "<" and `&gt;` instead of ">".
so what I'm getting is:

the output is utf-8 encoded and it still outputs the file with `&lt;`.

Here's my code:

```
for png in pngs:
    strtag = "<img src='"+png[4:]+"' /> <br/>"
    #cut out first 4 characters that were used to write to folder
    print((strtag))
    soup.find("div",{'id':'plotsdiv'}).append((strtag))
```

the print gives:

```
<img src='imgs//cummulative_PV_capacity_installed.png' /> <br/>
<img src='imgs//cummulative_PV_capacity_installed_zoom.png' /> <br/>
```

but the actual output:

```
soup.find("div",{"id":"plotsdiv"})
>> <div class="row" id="plotsdiv">
&lt;img src='imgs//cummulative_PV_capacity_installed.png' /&gt;      
&lt;br/&gt;&lt;img src='imgs//cummulative_PV_capacity_installed_zoom.png' /&gt;     
&lt;br/&gt;&lt;img src='imgs//monthly_install_cap_agg.png' /&gt; &lt;br/&gt;</div>
```

Comment: When you give the  `append()` method a string, it assumes you want that string to show up in the browser. Therefore, certain HTML elements are escaped so that happens. What you want to do is create a new tag object using the `.new_tag()` method, or else parse your `strtag` to get a tag, and then append that instead.

Comment: Yes. That works. Thanks. I searched a lot and didn't find a similar question, and was hesitant to post because I was suspicious there was already one posted, though I couldn't find it. Turns out I was right. This has already been answered as mentioned above.